# Inherited method seems to be disowned by its ancestor

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm still getting, "The type OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)"

even though I've implemented the method in two places (placed in both places via "Quick Fix").

This is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_activity);

        // try commenting the button code out to see if that lets it run...
        Button buttonAuthorizeUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAuthorizeUsers);
        buttonAuthorizeUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent configure = new  Intent(OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this, Configure_Activity.class);  
                OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this.startActivity(configure);
            }});
    }

/*  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent configure = new  Intent(OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this, Configure_Activity.class);  
        OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this.startActivity(configure);
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity` claims to implement `View.OnClickListener`, you need to have the `onClick()` implementation that you have commented out, otherwise it will not compile.

Also, you are *separately* presently creating an anonymous inner class instance of `View.OnClickListener` that you are passing to `setOnClickListener()`. It too will need an implementation of `onClick()`.

If you are thinking that you should only need one of these, then either remove `implements View.OnClickListener` from your class declaration *or* pass `this` to `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: When I just keep the "standalone" onClick(), and change the code to "buttonAuthorizeUsers.setOnClickListener(this);" the widgets on the form don't display. If I comment that line out, they do display, but of course the button click does nothing... (Catch 22)

Comment: @ClayShannon: Make sure you actually have a `buttonAuthorizeUsers` `Button` in your `ondemandandautomatic_activity.xml` layout resource. The only situation I can think of that would have the symptoms you describe is if you are getting a `NullPointerException` because `buttonAuthorizeUsers` did not exist. That should raise a "Force Close" dialog, unless you have some sort of global exception handler in place that is eating the error without telling you about it.